# Where the Speed Control Effect Strip Modifier was moved to?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am using the VSE in 2.80. It used to be in the lower right corner in the default Video Editing layout, with the modifiers.

Answer (score -1):

Silly me! I was looking in the wrong place! 
Once you select the video strip, then Shift A, and at the bottom find "Effect strip".